# Why can “I want to X” turn into “I want to” but “I look forward to X” cannot become “I look forward to”?

Tags: grammar

The following are correct:

- I want to eat this.
- I want to! (e.g. in response to a suggestion)
- I forgot to do it.
- I forgot to! (e.g. in response to “Did you do it?”)

However, while the following are correct:

- I look forward to eating.
- I look forward to it!
- I’ve changed my mind about eating.
- I’ve changed my mind about it!

The following are obviously wrong:

- **X** I look forward to!
- **X** I’ve changed my mind about!

Why? What’s the underlying rule here? I have a vague idea but would like a proper grammatical explanation since I’m trying to help an English learner who asked me this question. Thank you!

Comment: _look forward to_ **what**? _Changed my mind about_ **what**?

Comment: Syntactically, *"I look forward to eating"* is the same as *"I look forward to **the party**".* In both cases, ***to*** is a *preposition before a **noun***. That's completely different to *"I want to eat [this]",* where ***to*** is the ***infinitive marker*** (in a context where the infinitive verb ***eat*** can optionally be followed by an ***object*** - the thing to be eaten).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has to do with *ellipsis*. After "to" can be ellipted *to-infinitive clauses*, but not other grammatical elements. That is just a matter of usage. This can be deduced from *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* by Randolph Quirk et al. in the chapter "Pro-forms and ellipsis".

- He wanted to study physics, but she didn't want him to (study physics). (*"Study physics" is the ellipted part, which, if kept in the sentence does not make it incorrect, but it is then a rather unusual one.*)
- Babies have to crawl before they walk; it is pretty obvious that they have to (crawl).

> (OALD) **to look forward to** [ (user LPH) This verbal form is constructed with a noun phrase after "to" or an -ing-clause, not an infinitive clause.]
>
> - I am looking forward to the weekend.
> - We're really looking forward to seeing you again.

- <s>She was looking forward to become a full member.</s>

There is no possible ellipsis after "about" (usage).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation and for recommending these resources. As I suspected, “to look forward to” takes a noun phrase, and while we can use “it”, we cannot omit the noun phrase. I wanted to ask, what is “study physics” in “I want him to study physics”, is it (part of) a verb phrase? Because if so, it seems like we can say that we can ellipt a verb phrase to “to”, but not a noun phrase? If this is correct, it might serve as a good general answer.

Comment: "To study physics" is a to-infinitive clause, which is a type of non-finite clause, so called because the verb form is not conjugated (to study, studying, studied). That is right, after "to" you cannot ellipt nouns, nor can you ellipt -ing-clauses.

Comment: That clears it up enough for me, thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: It’s somewhat implied in the answer, but I think it’s worth spelling out that the _to_ in ‘I want you to [infinitive]’ and the one in ‘I look forward to [noun/gerund]’ **are not the same word** – they just happen to look the same. In the former, _to_ is a particle marking that the following verb is in the infinitive; in the latter, it is a preposition that takes a nominal entity (pronoun, noun phrase, gerund, etc.). ‘I look forward to going’ is structurally completely parallel to ‘I prevented him from going’, just with a different preposition.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The point of view I'm familiar with (that in the grammar I quote and also in OALD (OLD online)),  is that a verbal form suxh as "to make" is called a "to infinitive" (the term "splitting infinitives", which should really be "splitting to infinitives" shows clearly that the particle is part of the verbal form) and the form "make" is the _bare infinitive_, also called the _base form_;  this corresponds however to your understanding that "to" would be a particle  empty of meaning. However, if this is sometimes  true, it is not quite so simple: there is a certain duality  (1/2)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet in the use of this particle, and it does have meaning in some cases, as you can verify from [this definition](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/to_2) of it in OLD; therefore it is still something of  a preposition. (2/2)

Comment: The "to" in **look forward to** and for example **look up to** is a preposition. We need a noun after a preposition we do not elide any verb. For example: ***We look forward to it*** ("it" could refer to a party, a visit, hearing some news etc.) and *He has always been her hero and she will always look up to him* (admire) "him". If we take the literal interpretation of "look up to" we cannot say– "They look up to [paint]” or "They look forward to [win]’ You have to say: "They look up to *the* painting" and "They look forward to winning [the competition]”

Answer (score 0):

Infinitive clause complementation and non-repetition of the main verb (in spoken English).

There are four categories of verbs that trigger infinitive complementation:
Verbs of intention:
**plan, mean, aspire, aim,
propose, wish, resolve, long, promise, vow.**
*Some of them do not require repetition of the main verb*:

- Verbs involving atttempting to do something:
  begin, attempt, forgot,

[this answer is UNFINISHED, Will finish a bit later. Thanks]